# Git log does not show user name

Tags: git

My `git log` command does not show my user name. When I do `git log` I get:

```
commit c364356360035c33e5f7b596e0bfcbcaf9284252
Author: = <me@site.com>
Date:   Wed May 6 10:18:51 2015 +0200
```

- When I do `git config user.name`  i get `=`.
- When I do `git config --global user.name` I get my username.

When I do `git config user.name = Me` and then `git config user.name` I still get `=`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `.git/config` file writable?

Comment: Also, try with `git config user.name Me` (without assignment symbol)

Answer (score 0):

looks like in your local .git/config you have an empty user name.
try to edit the file and verify if this is the case.

If you don't see there your name/email in the local repo try to add --local to your config when setting the username/email